# How to make sure I've got all $_POST data in specific format

Tags: php, forms

Well I have a web page with some inputs.

Inputs are in some groups and all in one form.

Inputs can be added to page dynamically but all follow a naming rule: `numberA-numberB-any`. 
Inputs can also be removed from page. So I may have something like this at the end:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input name="3-1-c">

  <input name="8-2-d">
  <input name="8-3[]">
  <input name="8-3[]">

  <input name="17-2-a">
  <input name="17-2-d">
  ... a few or many other inpooots!
</form>
```

they're grouped due to numberA (2nd, 3rd and 4th inputs, are in group number 8)

then at the server-side with php; how can I create a loop that read all this input ordered by numberA (because I should perform some databasic actions for each numberA with all its subsets) and miss none of inputs.

```
while (have_groups_of_inputs(?)) { // inputs with same numberA part
  while (have_items_in_this_group(?)) {
    do_the_job();
  }
}
echo 'thanks!';
```

$_POST data sample:

```
Array
(
    [itemcount] => 4
    [formid] => 
    [title] => Your info

    [1-title] => First name
    [1-hint] => your name
    [1-eltype] => 1
    [1-1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [3-title] => Last name
    [3-hint] => 
    [3-eltype] => 1
    [3-1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [4-title] => Gender
    [4-hint] => 
    [4-eltype] => 2
    [4-0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Male
            [1] => Female
        )
)
```

Comment: Show the output of `print_r($_POST)` after submitting a sample of your form to the handling script (copy from the page source, so we can see the linebreaks and indentation) then explain again how you expect it to be ordered.

Comment: Try to do something like `foreach($_POST as $nane => $value) {}` and just use some functions to sanitize the output, so you can explode the string by using the character `-` and then re-arrange the elements in arrays according to their numberA, numberB and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can iterate through the $_POST array and bucket the values based on the key

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $parts = explode('-', $key);
    if(isset($parts[2])){
        $groups[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]] = $value; 
    }else{
        if(!isset( $groups[$parts[0]][$parts[1]])){
              $groups[$parts[0]][$parts[1]] = array();
        }
        $groups[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][] = $value;
    }
}
```

This should result in an array which looks like the following

```
{
   '3':{
       '1':{
           'c': value_for_3-1-c
       }
   },
   '8':{
       '2':{
           'd': value_for_8-2-d
       },
       '3':[
           value_for_8-3[0],
           value_for_8-3[1],
       ]
   },
   '17':{
        '2':{
            'a': value_for_17-2-a,
            'd': value_for_17-2-d
        }
   }
}
```

then if you want to loop over each item in group 8

```
foreach($groups[8] as $b=>$sub){
    foreach($sub as $key=>$value){
        echo $key . ': ' . $value; 
    }
}
```

would result in:

```
d: value for 8-2-d
0: value for 8-3[0]
1: value for 8-3[1]
```